# Data is duplicated and the output is shown two times. Possibly spreading error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

[image: I only enter the values one time and its gets duplicated[1]]Here the output is duplicated 2 times and I know it is something in the return format. How could this be fixed?

```
 export const addToDo = (state, action) => {
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
      const { name, email, phone } = action;
      const tempTodo = state.data;
      console.log("====================================");

      return {
        data: [...tempTodo, { name: name, email: email, phone: phone }]
      };
    };
```

//This is for store

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      addToDos: (name, email, phone) =>
        dispatch(toDoActions.addToDo(name, email, phone)),

      toggleToDo: (index, name, email, phone) =>
        dispatch(toDoActions.toggleToDo(index, name, email, phone))
    },
    dispatch
  );
};
```

//this is the button on click function

```
onButtonClick()
{
this.props.addToDos(name, email, phone);
}
```

//reducer exporting

```
export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.ADD_TO_DO]: addToDo,
});
```

Comment: can you put the code where is calling to addTodo( all places...)

Comment: try: `data: [].concat(tempTodo, { name: name, email: email, phone: phone })`

Comment: By duplicate you mean, another todo with same name, email and phone?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I have logged that, the function is called only one time : )

Comment: @quirimmo Its still duplicating the data

Comment: @RakeshMakluri yes brother.. every field is same .. It gets copied

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the bug you're experiencing?

Comment: @DrewReese I will attach screenshots

Comment: Screen shots of output isn't a MCVE to reproduce.  What if your render code is outputting twice for some reason.  What if something outside the reducer it triggering another action?  This reducer code doesn't look wrong, a bit verbose, but not incorrect.  [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v4w8vyq5n)

Comment: Well the below answer worked fine for me.. Thanks for your output @DrewReese I surely learnt fomratting from you and will keeep in mind for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export const addToDo = (state, action) => {
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
      const { name, email, phone } = action;
      const tempTodo = state.data || [];
      console.log("====================================");
      let newData = tempTodo;
      const duplicate = tempTodo.find(todo => todo.name === name && todo.email === email && todo.phone ==== phone);
      if(!duplicate) {
        newData = [...tempTodo, { name: name, email: email, phone: phone }]
      }
      return {
        data: newData
      };
    };
```

Comment: So, something is adding the same todo again or dispatching the action twice.  This just keeps duplicates from being added.

Comment: It's a hack I understand.. Something is adding the same todo again.. But I am pretty sure action is triggered only once because when i logged the output of reducer it is  not in synchronous manner like if same reducer is called twice then the logging is in systematic  manner but not in this case.. After using the spread operator the data is possibly addened up

Comment: @DrewReese I still wait for your answer though if you have a better answer to stop duplicacy

Comment: @RishavKumar We would need to see a bit more code to get better context.  I just wanted to point out that this solution is only a bandaid, but glad it worked for you.

Comment: Updated my question @DrewReese